# Can Camunda be integrated with Apache Pulsar?

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler, camunda-plugin

I am looking into Camunda for using as an orchestration framework and was wondering if it can be integrated with our Pulsar topics ? I saw the support for Kafka and couldnt find anything on apache pulsar.

Answer (score 1):

You can contact Camunda via a ticket in Github.

I don't see direct Apache Pulsar support.

If you run KoP (Kafka on Pulsar) module on Apache Pulsar it should work fine as most things work that way.

See https://github.com/riferrei/is-using-kop-a-good-idea

https://docs.streamnative.io/platform/v1.0.0/concepts/kop-concepts